# Get std::variant types at compile time

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variant

Suppose we have defined somewhere:

```
using mytype_t = std::variant<int, float>;
```

I want to retrieve all possible types that coud be stored by `mytype_t`. I have checked the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). There is no member types defined that I can use (something like: `mytype_t::value_types`).

I am trying to do something like this:

```
using myvectype_t = std::variant<std::vector<mytype_t::value_types>...>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a special member for that, because the information is all right there in the type:

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct foo;

template <typename...V>
struct foo< std::variant<V...>> {
    using type = std::variant<  std::vector<V> ...>;
};


int main() {
    using vari = std::variant<int,double>;
    using varivect = std::variant< std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>;
    std::cout << std::is_same<foo<vari>::type,varivect>::value;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/4ffv1d)

Comment: @UsingCpp hm good question. I would say yes, but gcc accepts it without

Comment: No, `typename` is only required when the right side has a dependent type. `foo<vari>` is not a template but a concrete class.

Comment: fwiw, both gcc and clang accept it with and without `typename`

Comment: Using `template <template<typename> V, typename... Args>` should be possible to do the alias template declaration.. Unfortunately I don't know. :(

Comment: @UsingCpp alias templates cannot be partially specialized (https://godbolt.org/z/dE9v6s). removed the ps ;)